# Planilha gerada com Openpyxl com erro de conteúdo

Tags: python, openpyxl

Estou executando um código Python que gera uma planilha, o código é executado até o final sem apresentar nenhum erro, porém quando eu vou abrir a planilha apresenta o erro " Estamos com um problema em um conteúdo da planilha. Você quer que tentemos recuperar o máximo que der?"

o código que usei para gerar a planilha é este:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

#lista_planilha_excedente é uma lista que o método abaixo recebe por parâmetro

def criar_planilha_caracteres(self,lista_planilha_excedente):

        wb = Workbook()
        ws1 = wb.active
        ws1.title = "Linhas com campos com execesso de caracteres"

        ws1.cell(row=1,column=1,value="Campo1")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=2,value="Campo2")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=3,value="Campo3")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=4,value="Campo4")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=5,value="Campo5")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=6,value="Campo6")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=7,value="Campo7")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=8,value="Campo8")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=9,value="Campo9")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=10,value="Campo10")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=11,value="Campo11")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=12,value="Campo12")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=13,value="Campo13")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=14,value="Campo14")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=15,value="Campo15")
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=16,value="Campo16")

        ind_linha_planilha = 2
        for lista_da_linha in lista_planilha_excedente:
            ind_coluna_planilha = 1
            for celula in lista_da_linha:
                ws1.cell(row=ind_linha_planilha,column=ind_coluna_planilha,value=celula)
                ind_coluna_planilha +=1
            ind_linha_planilha +=1
        
        wb.save('Linhas com excesso Caractere.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo do erro:

está nesta linha:
ws1.title = "Linhas com campos com execesso de caracteres"

o nome dado a planilha está com mais de 31 caracteres, reduzi o nome e funcionou.